# Android: Shape in REAL background

Tags: android, xml, background, styles, shapes

Im using a shape for the background of my activities.
The looks great but works only for ~90% because the shape is lying OVER some elements like buttons or textviews.

Some buttons are displayed correctly but some others look like they are in the background of the shape?!

Greets

Code:
http://pastie.org/private/xxrgz6gqjnk1ufjyc6ms6a

Comment: Check the order of views in your layout file. Things will be drawn from the top down i.e. the first thing in the layout file will be drawn first and the following on top of that in the order they are specified.

Comment: i posted a pastie-link to the code-snippets

Comment: Well you're setting the background of the RelativeLayout to that of your shape, so it makes sense if the contents are inside the background